# IIS URL Rewrite fails for angular "assets" folder

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I'm trying to deploy angular 6 project(with lazy load module routes) in IIS with URL Rewrite. Below is my folder structure

[image]

and below is my web.config file

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url=".*" />
             <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
     <outboundRules>
                       <rule name="CDN_ReWrite_Images" enabled="true" preCondition="IsHtml" stopProcessing="true">
                         <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)/(assets)/(.*)" />
                         <action type="Rewrite" value="http://localhost:4300/{R:3}" />
                         <conditions>
                         </conditions>
                       </rule>
                       <preConditions>
                         <preCondition name="IsHtml" logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                           <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                         </preCondition>
                       </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Angular routes are working fine. The Issue here is when my application tries to access the contents of asset folder it includes the asset as part of URL. I tried creating outbound rule as below to ignore asset folder. But that won't work.

The ideal route should be

```
http://localhost:4300/json/data_list.json
```

instead it tries to access

```
http://localhost:4300/assets/json/data_list.json
```

Let me know what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks